# cypress.io - wait for an lazy loaded js-file

Tags: cypress

we want to test a webpage that does an ajax-request after clicking a button.

We are able to wait for the response of this ajax-request by defining a cy.route()

```
cy.server()
cy.route("POST", '/exampleAjax').as('exampleAjax')
cy.get('.button').click()
cy.wait('@exampleAjax')
```

Within the onComplete-Block of the ajax-Response we create an script-Tag and insert it:

```
new Ajax.Request( "exampleAjax", {
    method: "post",
    parameters: {'data-id': dataID},
    onComplete: function(transport) {
        var snode = document.createElement('script');  
        snode.setAttribute('type','text/javascript');                  
        snode.setAttribute('src','/some.js');
        document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(snode); 
    }
});
```

Now we want to wait for some.js to be loaded and tried

```
cy.route("GET", '/some.js').as('some_js')
cy.wait('@some_js')
```

But this does not work. How can we achieve this?

Comment: I don't think the `onComplete` is actually triggering the get of `some.js`, it's just adding the script reference to DOM. Do you see anything in the console network tab?

Comment: yes - you are right. We don't get some.js within onComplete but reference it within the script-tag that is inserted in the DOM -> then some.js is loaded by the browser (can be seen in the network-tab of dev-tools). 

So how do we wait for some.js be loaded?

Comment: That's interesting, was wondering if the browser reacted to a dynamically added script tag. The next question is, does Cypress react to it. Where is the `cy.route("GET", '/some.js')` in relation to `cy.get('.button').click()`? You may need to set up the second route watcher before the action is initiated (but after `cy.server()`).

Comment: yes - we already set up a second route watcher: cy.route("GET", '/some.js').as('some_js'); cy.wait('@some_js'). But it seems it is not triggered.

Comment: I was asking ***where*** the `cy.route('/some.js')` is in relation to the button click, as it should be be between the `cy.server()` and the `.click()` - but your code indicates it is not. Perhaps you can show the complete test rather than fragments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not possible with cypress currently. Cypress team is working on network stubbing. Take a look at [this issue](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/1296).

Comment: Mother issue for all stuff related to Full network layer stubbing implementation - https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/687

Answer (score 3):

While we are still waiting for the feature request linked by Art713 we found a **workaround** for us:

We let cypress check for a global var / function that is defined within the lazy-loaded js-file:

```
cy.window().its('<any global var / function>')
```

In our case we also increased the defaultCommandTimeout within cypress.json in order to avoid a timeout after 4 seconds

```
{
  "defaultCommandTimeout": 10000
}
```